Convert PDE with boundary conditions into PDE with source term
I have a wave described by the 2D wave equation
$$
\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \nabla^2 u(t,x,y),
$$
with the boundary conditions $u(t,x,0) = f(t,x)\theta(t)$, and initial conditions $u(0,x,y) = u_t (0,x,y) = 0$.
We can see that this is basically a wave with a source at the x axis, so I would like to convert this into a problem of the form
$$
\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \nabla^2 u(t,x,y) + g(t,x,y),
$$
where $g$ is some source that is turned on at $t=0$ (and now we forget about the $u(t,x,0)$ condition).
My question is, how do I set $g$ so that this PDE is equivalent to the original problem?

Shouldn't the initial conditions be $u(0,x,y)=u_t(0,x,y)=0$?

@Gonçalo Indeed! Thank you for the correction.

Very nice question, although you might not like the answer. I don’t have a definitive answer, but I can give you an idea of the tools you need to know $g$. I will use the language of distributions, hoping it is not too advanced for you. The main thing I use is actually just the following: for a given function $f=f(t,x)$, I define the measure (or distribution)
$$ f\otimes\delta_{y=0} $$
by the formula
$$ \int \varphi(t,x,y)\,d(f\otimes\delta_{y=0}):=\int \varphi(t,x,0) f(t,x)\,dt\,dx. $$
Might look hard, but I am basically taking the 2D function $f$ and I look at it as a 3D measure supported on the hyperplane $\{y=0\}$ in $\mathbb R^3$ (or $\mathbb R_+\times\mathbb R^2$). It’s essentially like taking the number $1$ (a $0$-dimensional function) and looking at it as a Dirac delta $\delta_0$, which is a 1D measure defined on $\mathbb R$ (one dimension higher) supported on the $0$-dimensional subspace $y=0\in\mathbb R$. I need to make this definition because the forcing that you are looking for will not be a function, it will be precisely a measure supported on the hyperplane $\{y=0\}$.

If you have a solution $u$ of the PDE with the above boundary conditions, the equation $u_{tt}=u_{xx}+u_{yy}$ is not satisfied on the whole $\mathbb R_+\times \mathbb R^2$ in a distributional sense, but you expect that the equation holds on $(\mathbb R_+\times \mathbb R^2)\setminus \{y=0\}$. This means that the PDE has to have the form
$$ u_{tt}=u_{xx}+u_{yy}+H, $$
where $H\in \mathscr D’(\mathbb R_+\times \mathbb R^2)$ is some distribution supported on $\mathbb R_+\times\mathbb R\times\{0\}$.
Assume $u$, $f$, $\theta$ are smooth, and that $H$ can be writted as $H=h\otimes \delta_{y=0}$ with $h=h(x,t)$ being smooth, and call $F:=f\theta$. You have
$$ u_{tt}(t,x,0)=F_{tt}(t,x), $$
$$ u_{xx}(t,x,0)=F_{xx}(t,x), $$
$$ u_{yy}(t,x,0)= [F_{tt}(t,x)-F_{xx}(t,x)]+h(t,x), $$
the last equation being because of what we wrote above. For brevity, call $(\partial_t^2-\partial_x^2-\partial_y^2)=:\square$, and $(\partial_t^2-\partial_x^2)=:\square^x$. We have now, in a distributional sense over all $\mathbb R_+\times \mathbb R^2$,
$$ \square u=h \otimes\delta_{y=0} = (\square^x F-u_{yy}|_{y=0})\otimes \delta_{y=0}. $$
In other words,
$$ Lu=\square^x F \otimes \delta_{y=0}, $$
where
$$ Lu:=\square u+(u_{yy}|_{y=0}) \otimes \delta_{y=0}. $$
Now loosely speaking, if there is a way of inverting the operator $L$, you would have
$$ \square u=\square L^{-1}[(\square^x F) \otimes \delta_{y=0}], $$
and the right hand side will coincide with the forcing $H$ that we are looking for (it will be the function $g$ that you are looking for, except it will be a distribution supported on $\{y=0\}$). The operator $L$ does not look immediate to study a priori, and I don’t see any simplifications in the final formula at the moment, so this is pretty much what I can say. In principle, and more concretely, finding $L^{-1}$ means studying the equation
$$ Lv=f, $$
in particular, finding a solution $v$ with given forcing $f$. It is possible that $\square L^{-1}$ can be defined as a bounded operator acting on a suitable space of measures supported on $\{y=0\}$, in that case defining
$$ H:=\square L^{-1}(\square^x F \otimes \delta_{y=0}) $$
would make perfect sense, since $\square^x F \otimes \delta_{y=0}$ is indeed a measure supported on the hyperplane. Unless there is some simplification that I don’t see in the above formula for $H$ (I did not check that carefully), one probably needs to know some operator theory or functional analysis to study the operator $\square L^{-1}$, but the above should be the correct formula regardless (I am ignoring the initial data in this answer for simplicity; they have to play a role in the exact definitionof $L^{-1}$).
